Add project parameter programatically in SSIS dtproj
I am developing an extension to help with SSIS package development.
I need to set project parameters, so I do this code :
private void SetProjectParameters(EnvDTE.Project project, string parameterName, string value)
{
    ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();

    foreach(EnvDTE.ProjectItem item in project.ProjectItems)
    {
        if (itemType.FullName == "Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Shell.Project.Extensibility.ProjectItemExt")
        {
            var objectGetter = itemType.GetProperty("Object");
            var obj = objectGetter.GetValue(item);

            if(obj is Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Parameters parameters)
            {
                if(!parameters.Contains(parameterName))
                {
                    var parameter = parameters.Add(parameterName, TypeCode.String);
                    parameter.Value = parameterName;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

But it don't work. However, if then I add a second parameter by Visual Studio UI and save the modification, the programmatically added parameter is also saved in the file Project.params, but not visible in UI. Finally, if I unload/reload the dtproj, then the programmatically added parameter is visible in UI.

How to add a parameter project programmatically to dtproj?
